# Sailsjs Waterline many to many relationship with legacy database

Tags: sails.js, sails-mssqlserver

I have 2 domain User and Role and it has a relation to Many To Many. User has many Roles. When I run the application it creates the mapping table like `role_user__user_role`. I need to support legacy database where the table name is `UserRole`. Can anyone help me what I need to do to achieve the same?

User.js has an attribute like:

```
role: {
  collection: 'role',
  via: 'user'
}
```

and Role.js has an attribute like:

```
user: {
  collection: 'user',
  via: 'role'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use through associations, see [here](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/associations/through-associations).